# To reinsert a passphrase with ecryptfs-add-passphrase

Tags: ecryptfs

If I reinsert a passphrase with "ecryptfs-add-passphrase" 
I add an other passphrase or I change the passphrase ?
I think that I change but ... I'm not sure
thank's

Answer (score 0):

from `man ecryptfs-add-passphrase`

```
DESCRIPTION
       ecryptfs-add-passphrase is a utility to manually add a passphrase to the kernel keyring.
```

When you change the user password, the relevant adaptation of the encryption is performed automatically in the encryption system.

However, this mechanism does not apply if the administrator for another user sets a (new) password.

1. Create a backup

   ```
   cd /home/<user_name>/.ecryptfs
   cp -f wrapped-passphrase wrapped-passphrase.old
   ```
2. Note passphrase

   ```
   ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase wrapped-passphrase
   passphrase: <old_passphrase>
   ```
3. Optional: Change user password

   ```
   passwd
   ```
4. Protect passphrase with current user password

   ```
   ecryptfs-wrap-passphrase wrapped-passphrase
   ```

   The following prompts appear:

   ```
   Passphrase to wrap:  <noted_passphrase>
   Wrapping passphrase: <current_password>
   ```

Now you should log out, log back in and check the success of the above measure. If not successful, you have to log in with your username and reset your password with passwd in the console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>). If the login still does not work you can copy back the `wrapped-passphrase.old`.

[Source](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/ecryptfs/Nutzung)